# change tabulator's placeholder at runtime

Tags: tabulator

I bumped into the problem of how to change tabulator's placeholder at runtime. As it is suggested to ask questions on StackOverflow, here it is. There is an issue (closed - https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1415) having a suggested solution that I tried. Unfortunately, it throws an error during creation:

```
tabulator.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at s.redraw (tabulator.min.js:4)
    at e.h.redraw (tabulator.min.js:6)
    at ResizeObserver.<anonymous> (tabulator.min.js:12)
```

tabulator version is 4.9.3. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ivos/6pq75brv/3/

the setup is simple:

```
var data = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
var placeholder = $("<span>Waiting for data</span>");
var conf = {
//  placeholder: "Waiting for data",
  placeholder: placeholder,
  columns: [
    { title: "Id", field: "id", headerFilter: "input" },
  ],
  dataFiltered: (filters, rows) =>{
    placeholder.text(filters.length > 0 ? 'No Results': 'Waiting for data');
  },
};
var t = new Tabulator('#tbl', conf);
setTimeout(function(){ t.setData(data)}, 5000); // timeout is just to show the initial placeholder
```

If I apply a filter (i.e. 5) I got

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at s.redraw (tabulator.min.js:4)
    at e.h.redraw (tabulator.min.js:6)
    at ResizeObserver.<anonymous> (tabulator.min.js:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM you cannot manipulate elements from outside of it.

There is no built in way to change the place holder option once the table has been set.

That being said i can certainly point you to a very hacky way of achieving this, that i would recommend against because it manipulates internal variables and that may result in it not working in future, but it should achieve what you are hoping for.

So assuming you are creating your table on a variable called `table`, the following should work:

```js
table.options.placeholder = "new placeholder message";
```

Comment: Thanks, Oli. I can hack it, but I don't like it too for the same reasons. I just found this example in the issues (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1415) and tried to use it. This is where the error appeared. I'll leave it for now. Hopefully, in the future, such functionality will be added.